# How do I configure the Service Account keys in a Cloud Run container?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I created a backend in Go, which uses the Secrets Manager, and deployed it to Cloud Run. The problem is the Secret Manager api needs a [Service Account credential json file](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) to point to and that works on my local machine because I just specify the file path in a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, but I don't have the same convenience in a Cloud Run environment. How will my backend on Cloud Run specify its `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable so to speak?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you need this environment variable? How do you use it?

Comment: For Cloud Run, manage permissions via the service account assigned to Cloud Run. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation

[Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production?_gac=1.49547922.1586423078.EAIaIQobChMI8MPZvP7a6AIVw0PTCh0U2QKoEAAYASAAEgJjcvD_BwE&_ga=2.166171899.479023528.1587365266-774421598.1585640747)

> If the environment variable isn't set, ADC uses the default service
> account that Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, **Cloud Run**, App
> Engine, and Cloud Functions provide, for applications that run on
> those services.

Therefore to access the Secret Manager from Cloud Run, Application Default Credentials (ADC) will use the default service account of Cloud Run.

## EDIT

By default cloud run uses [compure engine service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity) `PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` which has the `EDITOR` role. You have 2 choices, either use default service account or deploy cloud run with [a non default service account that you created](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts) with the `Secret Manager Admin` role.

Comment: That was it. Just had to go to `EDIT & DEPLOY NEW REVISION` and select owner as the service account.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @marian.vladoi's great answer, in a nutshell, to access a GCP API (in your case Secret Manager API), you need to do two things:

1. Deploy your Cloud Run application with a specific Service Account using the `--service-account` option (or UI equivalent).
2. Give this Service Account permissions to do something (in this case, to access a secret).

Inside a Cloud Run container (or a GKE app, Cloud Run app, Cloud Functions app etc.) you don't need to specify a key with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. The necessary credentials are automatically obtained while you're running on Google Cloud in any GCP client library.

Comment: I added the "Secret Manager Admin" role to my "@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" service account and deployed a new container. Still getting a `Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource 'projects/my-project/secrets/API_KEY/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).` error.

Comment: `@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` sounds wrong. I'm not sure why you choose that account. That's not an account you own. Do a Google Search: `create service account google cloud` and please create a proper new svc account.